# Установка PHP PHANTOMJS на vps сервер

Tags: php, vps, phantomjs

Подскажите пожалуйста как установить PHP PHANTOMJS  на vps сервер.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gsfonts-x11 fonts-arphic-uming

cd /tmp/ && wget https://bitbucket.org`curl -s https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads | grep -E -o '/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2' | head -n 1` && tar xjf phantomjs-* && sudo mv `ls | grep 'phantomjs-' | head -n 1`/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/ && cd `ls | grep 'phantomjs-' | head -n 1` && sudo mkdir /usr/share/phantomjs && sudo mv examples/ /usr/share/phantomjs && cd

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
```

Решение под debian\ubuntu

Далее проверить версию и что всё в порядке phantomjs -v